# After ignore SSL certificate via Rest Assured get 401 for token request

Tags: java, ssl, ssl-certificate, token, rest-assured

After that I have found fix for this Exaptation,

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

fixed this Exaptation with code below:

```
request.config(RestAssured.config().sslConfig(new SSLConfig().allowAllHostnames().relaxedHTTPSValidation()));
```

I faced a problem can't to get token from response. I get 401 status code for authorization request, /token/missed. Have not idea why. 'cuz via Postman I should not set token in header for this request, request to get token. Probably somebody had faced this issue and know how to fix it?

```
   public EndPoints (String baseUrl) {
    RestAssured.baseURI = baseUrl;
    request = RestAssured.given();
    request.config(RestAssured.config().sslConfig(new SSLConfig().allowAllHostnames().relaxedHTTPSValidation()));
    request.header("Content-Type", "application/json");
    request.header("Accept","application/json");

}

public void authenticateUser(AuthorizationRequest authorizationRequest) {
    Response response = request.log().all().body(authorizationRequest).post(RoutApi.loginTo());
```

Comment: HTTP status 401 usually means that you are not authenticated. Either your credentials are wrong or you are not sending them correctly.

Comment: yep, you was so right =) it's my mistake. Had incorrect path